# Batch edit file properties by parsing filename text

Tags: windows, video, powershell, batch, rename

### Problem

I'm trying to batch process and organize some old video files. In order to catalog the files, I wanted to update some metadata so that it would show up in my catalog software, [abeMeda](https://abemeda.com/) (aka [neoFinder](https://cdfinder.de/)).

In this case, I'm parsing the timestamp out of files with names like `2000-12-24_18-56.00.mov`.

### Findings

I did a lot of research all day and have found a few things that should be memorialized:

1. Unlike images, video files are not as robust with their metadata. To update file properties (such as timestamps) it seems the best way to do it is in the file system itself. This is an oversimplification, but bottom line is that you don't always have common metadata properties that span all video file types.
2. [Exiftool](https://exiftool.org/) is a common recommendation for this type of activity and it has the ability to parse date and time from the filename, BUT it saves the resulting data in a metadata property that [isn't helpful for video](https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=8992.0) (see point #1). It's great for images but video is more finnicky.

   - Example: `exiftool "-createdate<filename" FILE`
3. `Exiftool` actually makes a copy of your video files when it makes these updates, so you literally double your disk usage if you don't limit the command appropriately. If you're working with a high-res video it could be an issue even with just one file. This also means it runs slowly when batch processing videos.
4. You can manually specify a date/time property in Powershell. In this example, I grabbed all .mov files in the current directory and changed them to the same creation date:

   - `Get-ChildItem *.mov | ForEach-Object {$_.CreationTime="03/10/2001"}`

*See my answer to this topic for how to better automate this process.*

Answer (score 0):

Here's the one-line powershell script to automatically update CreationTime based on the text in the filename:

```
Get-ChildItem *.mov -Recurse | ForEach-Object {$_.CreationTime=[DateTime]::ParseExact($_.BaseName,'yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm.ss',$null)}
```

### Explanation

1. `Get-ChildItem *.mov -Recurse` grabs all files in the current directory and all subfolders if they have the `.mov` extension
2. `| ForEach-Object {$_.CreationTime=...}` iterates through each file it found and updates the file's Creation Time

   - Presumably you could substitute another timestamp for `CreationTime`, such as `LastWriteTime` or `LastAccessTime`.
3. `[DateTime]::ParseExact($_.BaseName,'yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm.ss',$null)` is the logic that parses the date from the filename and passes it back to the property in #2.

   - Working from the middle out, `$_.BaseName` pulls in the filename.
   - `yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm.ss` is the format of the timestamp as it is written in the filename, so that powershell knows what it is looking at (this should be adjusted based on how the text appears in your files).
   - `[DateTime]::ParseExact` is the command the parses this text from the name and converts it into a date that powershell can use.

Answer (score 0):

that is a great explanation.
I am a novice.  Never used PowerShell .. I tried your answer and nothing happend .. no output in PowerShell and no change.

My example filename  .. 2001-04-12 04.45.33.m4v
My example script ..
Get-ChildItem *.m4v -Recurse | ForEach-Object {$*.CreationTime=[DateTime]::ParseExact($*.BaseName,'yyyy-MM-dd HH.mm.ss',$null)

What am I doing wrong .. do I run it at directory prompt or when >> appears.

If I run at directory th epropt changes to >> after I run it.

Thanks
Adam

Comment: You forgot the underscore in your `$_.CreationTime`...

Comment: I got it to work .. but .. some of my filenames are longer than just the date.  The datetime is always at the start.  How do I just use the start of the filename? e.g. "2010-09-09 13,22.54 IMG_0071.mov"

Comment: If single digits in the date/time are always padded to 2 digits, you can do a simple fixed-length substring operation on $_.BaseName and pass that to the `ParseExact()` method. If length of date/time varies, you can use a regualr expression.

Comment: Thanks. How do I do that?   I am a novice.

Comment: Is the length of the date/time portion fixed or varied???

Comment: I can make it fixed.  Thanks

Comment: `[DateTime]::ParseExact($_.BaseName.Substring(0,19),'yyyy-MM-dd HH.mm.ss',$null)`

Comment: this is clearly not an answer.